# Incorrect symbol is displayed in Monospace font with xelatex

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}
\begin{document}

\ttfamily
◦ Fira Mono
\end{document}
```

which is UTF-8 encoded and uses some Unicode symbols in Monospace font. The font seems to contain the correct glyph because I use it as default font in Emacs and it displays correctly. However, when I do

```
xelatex test.tex
```

symbol is not displayed correctly:

[image: test.pdf]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong, but the Fira Mono font lacks that glyph.

For the missing glyphs you can set up a fallback font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmonofont{Fira Mono}
\newfontfamily{\fallbackmono}{FreeMono}

\newunicodechar{◦}{%
  \texttt{\makebox[\fontcharwd\font`a]{\fallbackmono ◦}}%
}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily
◦ Fira Mono

Fira Mono x

\end{document}
```

This assumes the character is only used in monospaced context; the definition can be improved for other cases. FreeMono is used just by way of example, any font having the glyph can be used.

[image]

Comment: That's puzzling because, as I said, the glyph is displayed in emacs when I use this font... Does this mean emacs does some replacement? Anyway, thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: @insitu Emacs uses a fallback chain of fonts, a mechanism which is not available in XeTeX